# Can we return pointer to new static array from the same function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, static

Is there a way to return a new array allocated with the static keyword after each invocation of a function? I can create a new array if i make a clone to the function, but not from the same function.

Consider the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *CrArray1(void);
char *CrArray2(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *p1 = CrArray1();
    strcpy(p1, "Hello, ");

    char *p2 = CrArray1();
    strcat(p2, "World");

    char *q1 = CrArray2();
    strcpy(q1, "Different String");

    printf("p1 is : %s\n", p1);
    printf("q1 is : %s\n", q1);

    return 0;
}

char *CrArray1(void)
{
    static char Array[128];
    return Array;
}

char *CrArray2(void)
{
    static char Array[128];
    return Array;
}
```

Comment: Yes, returning of local static object address is OK. But it is the same object for each call to the same function. And different if functions are different.

Comment: @Serhio That's not what question is about. OP wants to return **new** array from **each invocation of a function**

Comment: No, there isn't. Objects with static storage are placed into a special memory section by the compiler. So they must all be known at build time.

Comment: @machine_1 Can you please describe your **actual** problem? Why do you want those arrays to be static? Short answer is no, static memory is not allocated at run time

Comment: You don't get a **new** array for each invocation of the function. That is absolutely not what `static` does. In contrary `static` ensures it is the same array and that it exists for the whole program execution. So the answer is no.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is memory reserved for them even if i don't call the function ?

Comment: @machine_1, of course. Although it won't be initialized until you do enter.

Comment: And if you are going the good path of dynamic allocations, please have a designated `CrArray1Release` function, even if it only calls `free`. It's good design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `static` objects *by definition* have only one instance.

You'll need to use `malloc()` and callers of your function will need to `free()` the memory.

Answer (score 1):

If at compile time you know how many times you are going to call the function then following can be used:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_TIMES_FUNCTION_WILL_BE_CALLED 10
char *CrArray1(void)
{
    static int i = -1;
    static char Array[NUMBER_OF_TIMES_FUNCTION_WILL_BE_CALLED][128];
    ++i;
    return Array[i];
}
```

Note: `NUMBER_OF_TIMES_FUNCTION_WILL_BE_CALLED` has to be a reasonable number.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't.

wikipedia:

> static is used to store the variable in the statically allocated memory instead of the automatically allocated memory.

so if you add after `q1`:

```
char *q2 = CrArray2();
strcpy(q2, "Another String");
```

and print `q2`, you will get:

`p1 is : Hello, World
   q1 is : Another String
   q2 is : Another String`

That means the `local static` variable still points to the same memory.
So the result is not we want.

But if you use the `malloc` to require a new memory in function. Each time the pointer that function returned will point to different memory. so there is no influence of those variables.

More about `static` you can refer [what does static means in a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572550/4168837)